# How can I retrieve the data from my entry box in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am programming a gui for a little project I'm working on which requires me to have multiple pages which I can switch between. I use classes (as seen below) to set up these pages. I now struggle with getting the data from an entry box as I am not yet familiar with OOP and am pretty new to Tkinter and Python in general.

```
from tkinter import *



#Create login screen
class login(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        entry_password = StringVar(self)
        entry_label = Label(self, text="Enter Password").place(relx = 0.5, rely=0.45, anchor="center")
        entry_box = Entry(self, textvariable=entry_password)
        entry_box.place(relx = 0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="center")
        submit_button = Button(self, text="Submit", command=print(entry_password.get())).place(relx = 0.5, rely=0.55, anchor="center")




#Create password list screen
class password_list(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        test = Label(self, text="Password list")
        test.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)




#Create main frame
class main(Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        buttonframe = Frame(self)
        buttonframe.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        login_screen = login(self)
        login_screen.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        login_screen.lift()

        password_list_screen = password_list(self)
        password_list_screen.place(in_=container, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        Button1 = Button(buttonframe, text="Lift Password list", command=password_list_screen.lift)
        Button2 = Button(buttonframe, text="Lift Login screen", command=login_screen.lift)
        Button1.pack(side="left")
        Button2.pack(side="left")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    main_screen = main(root)
    main_screen.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.wm_geometry("1200x700")
    root.mainloop()
```

When I run the program, enter text into the entry box and press the button it doesn't print anything. How can I properly retrieve the data from the entry box? I need it to validate it as a password to decrypt a file.

Comment: `entry_box.get()` will hold the value of your entrybox

Comment: and since you said your new to python and tkinter, i would recommend to start without using classes (its really easy) and then implement classes later on. But its not a bad idea to start from the difficult too :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use '.get'.

```
v = StringVar()
e = Entry(master, textvariable=v)
e.pack()

v.set("a default value")
s = v.get()
```

You can view more at the [documentation](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm).

Comment: When I set my varibale to be a specific value it just prints out the value when i first start the program but not when i press the button...why?

Comment: @Sergeant_Keks becuase you used the `()` after the function name in the `Button`s command argument. Removing that should be okay

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to fix it with the help of a very well done youtube video. I just needed to change one line:

```
submit_button = Button(self, text="Submit", command=lambda: submit(entry_password)).place(relx = 0.5, rely=0.55, anchor="center")
```

I don't quite get why lambda makes this work but it does...can anybody explain this to me?

Comment: Well, in short, `lambda` allows you to pass in arguments for your functions, without it , function would not execute properly.